# Keyboard shortcut in Word 2011 to send document as email attachment?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mail.app, email, ms-office

In MS Office 2011 for Mac, there is a useful menu option under:

File > Share > Email (as Attachment)...

It's a very quick way to get from editing to email.  Is there a way to assign this to a keyboard shortcut? I'd be be glad if I can do this with the already-installed tools, but would consider a third party tool as well.

**What I have tried:**  Word's own keyboard tool under "Tools > Customize Keyboard..."  I can find no listing of this menu item (under 'file' 'share' or 'email').

Nor does the OSX (Mountain Lion) Keyboard Shortcuts preferences tool help.  I've tried a shortcut for both "Share" and "E-mail (as Attachment)".  The first one shows up in the MS Word "File" Menu, but does nothing in practice except blink the menu header.  The second one simply does nothing.

[image: An attempt at keyboard shortcuts]

Is there a way to set up a keyboard shortcut for this option?  If not, do you have any other quick solution for achieving the same effect?  These are often files that I receive via email, so I'd rather not have to explicitly save them, note the location, then attach them from within an email program.  I want a quick edit & send.  The copy n my outbox is enough of a backup for me.

Comment: I don't have office 2011 to check, but I know you have to type the exact menu item name in the shortcut area, are you sure there isn't an ellipsis after "(as Attachment)"? …

Comment: Thats' it!  I assumed the ellipsis was extraneous.  If you like, add this as an answer and I'll accept it  If you don't care about the rep score, I'll do it just to close it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to type the exact menu item name in the shortcut area, so make sure that you have the ellipsis: "E-mail (as Attachment)…"

You can type an ellipsis character by holding down <kbd>option</kbd> and typing <kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: Ah, that keyboard tip is a good one.  I originally had to copy-paste that ellipsis from your comment above.

Comment: I learned it trying to save characters in twitter.